# Как сделать запрос xpath в текущей ноде

Tags: php, парсер, xpath

Подскажи плиз, как можно в текущей ноде выполнить xpath запрос:
Например есть список нод:

```
    $query = '//body/div'
    $document = new \DOMDocument();
    @$document->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new \DOMXpath($document);
    $nodeList = $xpath->query($query);
```

Как теперь для каждой ноды из $nodeList выполнить еще один $xpath->query()?
Например примерно так:

```
    foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
        $newNodeList  = $node->query('./p');
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/domxpath.query.php запрос относительно узла, есть второй параметр относительно какого узла сделать запрос

Comment: Там в примере вторым параметром идёт относительно чего надо установить query `$xpath->query($query, $tbody);`

Comment: Поняли, что имеется ввиду или пример написать?

Comment: Спасибо! так работает )